# Is it not possible to update a task with lead(whoid) and opportunity (whatid)?

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, leads, tasks, update

As per document, i found that whoid can be lead/contact and whatid can be account/case/opportunity/custom obj and others. I am updating a task with leadid as whoid and opportunityid as whatid but getting error

```
url - services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Task/:taskid
method - patch
payload - {"WhoId":"<leadid>","WhatId":"<opportunity>"}
headers - Authorization: Bearer <api_key>
```

```
[
    {
        "message": "field integrity exception: WhoId, WhatId (cannot specify whatID with lead whoID)",
        "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
        "fields": [
            "WhoId",
            "WhatId"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Looks related to this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eUwQAAU)

Comment: thank you so much @Swetha

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is related to the [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eUwQAAU)

According to this,

> Actual Results: The review error is shown the label info (field integrity exception: WhoId, WhatId (cannot specify whatID with lead whoID: 1)

> Expected Results: The proper error would be presented reading, "You can’t relate an account, opportunity, or other object to a task already related to a lead."

> Workaround:
> Instruct users that when they populate a Lead record into an activities Name field that they will not be able to associated an additional record via the Related To field.